# iOSで画面に配置した画像を、移動、リサイズ、回転を簡単に行えるライブラリを探しています。

Tags: objective-c

iOSで画面に配置した画像を、移動、リサイズ、回転を簡単に行えるライブラリを探しています。

移動、リサイズに関しては、以下のライブラリを使用すれば目的のことは実現できそうなのですが、
https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView

回転が実現できていません。

実現したいことは、UIRotationGestureRecognizerで回転させるのではなく、
画像の四隅にあるグリップとは別に、回転を行うアイコンを表示して
それを円の軌跡で動かすと回転する動きを実現したいのです。

お助けてください。